# React routing on landing page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to learn react-routing thats why making small application.

I have 5 page

1. Login
2. Signup
3. Panel (Landing page)
4. User
5. Error

In app.js

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  let history = useHistory();
  return (
    <Router>
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path={paths.login}>
            <LoginWrapper history={history} />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path={paths.signup}>
            <SignupWrapper history={history} />
          </Route>
          <PrivateRouting path={paths.dashboard}
            isAuthenticated={user}
            history={history}
            component={Panel} />
          <Route component={ErrorPage} />
        </Switch>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

after successful login its redirected panel(landing page)

Panel.js

```
import React, { useContext }  from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from '../../Components/Header/Header';
import { UserContext } from '../../Utils/UserContext';
import {paths} from '../../Constants/Paths';
import User from '../User/User';

const Panel =(props)=>{
  const {history}=props;
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      Home Page
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path={paths.user}>
            <User user={user} history={history} />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Panel;

Panel.propTypes = {
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.object,
    PropTypes.bool]),
  history:PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};


import React from 'react';
import {
  Route,
  Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const PrivateRouting = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    isAuthenticated
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to="/" />
  )} />
);
export default PrivateRouting;

PrivateRouting.propTypes = {
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.object,
    PropTypes.bool]),
  component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
};

PrivateRouting.defaultProps = {
  name: false
};
```

when i try to redirect /user(paths.user) it automaticly redirect to Error page

How can i create routing in panel

Comment: Can you also list your PrivateRouting component code?

Comment: editted the question

Comment: I am just guessing that a route for "/" is not defined in your routing, that is why it is showing the error page. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: does removing <Router> from Panel solves the problem?

Comment: @devd accually login is "/"

Comment: @ishaba sorry but no

Comment: So after login you see Home Page right? and how then you making redirect to user?

Comment: after login i am seeing /panel(panel.js) in panel.js there is <Header in the header i have a link 
 <Link to={paths.user}>
                <Icon iconType="user" padding="15px" />
              </Link>

Comment: i can make something like 
let routes = ....

if(isUserAuthenticated){
routes = ...}

but is there a way like mine ?